# Can I joint 2 dataframes in R by an ID column and a nearest date value

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I am trying to join common ID values in 2 dataframes to their most closely matched  date within R. I have a list with demographic data and another with blood samples that have been collected. Unfortunately the dates of both visits do not match exactly. Therefore i would like to pair up the most closely occuring entries for each ID by date.

The following code represents what I would like to do. I want to merge all columns from df1 and df2 by common ID values and the most closely matching date per entry. ID no 1 in this case would have 2 entries for example.

```
library(lubridate)


df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 3, 3, 5),
              var2 = c("Dog", "Dog", "Cat", "Cat", "Hamster"),
                  Date = c("01-01-2022","02-01-2022" , "07-12-2022", "03-02-2023", "05-12-2022"))
df1$Date <- dmy(df1$Date)


df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 3, 3, 5),
              Date = c("07-01-2022","04-12-2022" , "10-12-2022", "04-02-2023", "15-12-2022"))

df2$Date <- dmy(df2$Date)
```

Comment: @Maël answer should do the trick. You could also use `which.closest` from the `birk` package that find the closest date to make a new column in df1 to further join with df2.

Comment: FYI, I opened an issue for using `closest` in either direction, see [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/6686)

Answer (score 2):

You can merge, then compute the `diff`erence and keep the closest:

```r
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  inner_join(df2, by = "ID", multiple = "all") %>% 
  slice_min(abs(Date.x - Date.y), n = 1, by = c(ID, Date.x))

  ID    var2     Date.x     Date.y
1  1     Dog 2022-01-01 2022-01-07
2  1     Dog 2022-01-02 2022-01-07
3  3     Cat 2022-12-07 2022-12-10
4  3     Cat 2023-02-03 2023-02-04
5  5 Hamster 2022-12-05 2022-12-15
```

Note that `join_by` cannot really help here since [`closest` does not accept  `==`](https://community.rstudio.com/t/dplyr-1-1-0-new-rolling-join-feature-join-by-closest-value/154218).